Springfox - Swagger UI - "Unable to infer base url...or when the API is behind an API Gateway" - error with ipv6 host, for ipv4 swaggerui works fine
When I  try to access https://my-ipv4-adress/api/swagger-ui/index.html , it works perfectly fine for me. However, when I try to access https://my-ipv6-address/api/swagger-ui/index.html , I get a popup saying

"Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet
registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is
the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if
the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the
base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location
manually: "

I tried referring other posts + the springfox doc https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-swagger-ui , but all of them mostly talk about springboot based configuration / spring security related issues. For my case, I am using Spring framework (not springboot) and no spring security involved here.
Hence, It's mainly related to ipv6 as with ipv4 address I don't have any issue accessing the swagger UI at all.
In springfox-swagger-ui/build.gradle , I am using swaggerUiVersion = '5.2.0'
Are you aware of any known issue for ipv6 support for springfox swagger ui?
Note: The backend is under apigateway and no spring security involved here.

Springfox is deprecated and obsolete for like 4 - 5 yrs now and is no longer supported. Springdoc is the new project.

Oh Okay. So if we integrate Springdoc with our Spring based legacy app (not springboot but Spring only) , do you think Springdoc is well supported for that kind of project and does Springdoc support ipv6 as well properly ?

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/ab5868471cdbaf54dac01af12933fe0437cf2b01/springfox-swagger-ui/src/web/js/springfox.js#L45 - This where the exception is thrown in springfox swagger UI codebase. But under which scenario of ipv6 , this will be thrown any idea?
